# Setter isn't always triggered

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I use a bindable variable that represents a Model and pass it down thru several nested components.

Top level component is my variable:

```
[Bindable]
private var meetingInfo:MeetingInfoModel;
```

I initialize it in the handler for the "preinitialize" event:

```
meetingInfo = MeetingInfoModel.getInstance();
```

I then pass it thru to 1 component:

```
<meetingViewStack:MeetingViewStack meetingInfo="{meetingInfo}"/>
```

In that component I have the following:

```
private var _meetingInfo:MeetingInfoModel;

public function set meetingInfo( model:MeetingInfoModel ):void{
    _meetingInfo = model;}

[Bindable]
public function get meetingInfo():MeetingInfoModel{
    return _meetingInfo;
        }
```

I then pass that variable to another nested component:

```
<documentShare:DocumentPanel meetingInfo="{meetingInfo}"/>
```

Where I have the same setter/getter set up. Then I pass it again to another nested component:

```
<documentShare:AttachmentFilesPanel meetingInfo="{meetingInfo}" />
```

In that component I have an ItemRenderer for a DataGroup component where it binds to "meetingInfo":

```
<s:DataGroup id="attachmentsList"
                 width="100%"
                 clipAndEnableScrolling="true"
                 dataProvider="{meetingInfo.docsAndAttachmentsList}"
                 itemRenderer="com.fmr.transporter.view.documentShare.DocumentUploadRenderer"
                 visible="{meetingInfo.docsAndAttachmentsList.length > 0}">`enter code here`
```

As I update the "meetingInfo.docsAndAttachmentsList" ArrayCollection, the setters in each nested component get called correctly, until....

...and this is an AIR app, mind you...

I log out and back in. Then, the setter/getter in the last nested component is not fired this time.

Why, oh why, would this happen?

I've been troubleshooting for a couple days and cannot figure it out for the life of me.

Thanks for any helpful tips!!

Comment: @fsbmain's answer is correct. However if you have to pass instances of a model objects all the way down the display hierarchy, possibly passing through objects that do not care about this particular model, I would consider using an IoC (Inversion of Control) container to inject the data only where it is needed. Currently [SwiftSuspenders](https://github.com/tschneidereit/SwiftSuspenders) is my weapon of choice, because it is the only 'framework' out there that does only that and does not add any so-called MVC functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `MeetingInfoModel.getInstance();` hints that `MeetingInfoModel` is a singleton, is it? If so, setter will be triggered only once, because of the mxmlc generates the check that objects instance changed, the generated code for SDk 4.5.1 will be like this:

```
[Bindable(event="propertyChange")]
public function set meetingInfo(value:MeetingInfoModel):void
{
    var oldValue:Object = this.meetingInfo;
    if (oldValue !== value)
    {
        this._883716727meetingInfo = value;
       if (this.hasEventListener("propertyChange"))
           this.dispatchEvent(mx.events.PropertyChangeEvent.createUpdateEvent(this, "meetingInfo", oldValue, value));
    }
}
```

so if you didn't recreate instance of `MeetingInfoModel` the setter will not be triggered.

Comment: Yes, it is a singleton and I'm definitely not recreating the instance of MeetingInfoModel; I'm only updating the ArrayCollections inside it that I use. Maybe that's the piece I'm missing.

Comment: If so, check the triggering of _set dataProvider_ in _attachmentsList_ list, it should work, rather than setting of _meetingInfo_